# How do I say organize in Japanese as in organize an event?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I am aware of the word for organizing a cabinet, organizing a room, but what is the word when one wants to say that a person organized an event, as in a person arranging an event or a gathering?

Comment: I think a work like the person in charge would be a good fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

企画する would be a good one I think.

Comment: Do you mean 計画する?

Comment: @GeneTunney No, it should be [企画]{きかく}する. I think you could also use [主催]{しゅさい}する. The one who does 企画 or 主催 would be called a 主催者, or often a [幹事]{かんじ} in the case of a smaller party or gathering.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question for me as I came across the same problem several times in the past (that is, realized that in several occasion I was not sure how to properly translate "organize" referred to an event).

After some research and asking around a little bit, probably for the specific case of an "event" I learned that the best match would be 計画{けいかく}する。

To make sure I remembered correctly I run simple google search for "イベントを計画する". It returned 50.100 results, which makes that likely (very empirically speaking) to be a correct expression.

I also checked ib weblio for sample sentences for [organize](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/Organize) and indeed there is one example using 計画する just to refer to a generic event.

In general, however, it is interesting to see how a general word such as "organize" in English might not have a single translation. Rather, the choice for a correct word to translate "organize" seems to depend very much on what is that you have to organize.

A few example are 整理{せいり}する (quite general, for data, questions, thoughts etc), 組織{そしき}する (generally related to political things, like parties, agencies etc), as well as a simple 準備{じゅんび}する that is very widely used as well (after all "prepare" and "organize" have quite a similar meaning).

Edit: In particular, since I noticed that you also mentioned a "gathering", in that case also 催{もよお}す and 主催{しゅさい}する are widely used.

Comment: Yes, the organize I had referred to about organizing a room, etc. in my question was 整理する. I also had previously asked someone Japanese about organize in the context of an event and they said 準備する, as you have mentioned. I thought that was a good one, but somehow didn't feel that it was an exact match. 計画する is another one I'd put in the same category as 準備する. Maybe there just isn't a perfect match!

Comment: Well, as far as my experience goes 計画する should be pretty close (this at least based on some discussions with some native speakers).
However as Miki said actually yeah 企画する also seem to be a good match. Reading the romaji I didn't connect immediately and I also thought he/she might have meant "keikaku". Anyway, after all  both 計 and 企 may have the meaning of "plan" among other things so I guess in the end adding 画 makes two kind of synonyms?